# Oauth2 Public Client with client credentials

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, m2m, clientcredential

I have some native desktop apps that needs to authenticate as clients with an Authorization Server implementing OAuth2 and OIDC. Since I do not have to impersonate an user on my Authorization Server I've chosen "Client Credentials" as the flow to authenticate them. This way I can authenticate this applications as clients on the Authorization Server.

I was wondering if this flow is suited for a native desktop app or, since I cannot consider this type of applications as confidential clients (I probably do not have a secure way to store the client secret), I should use a different Oauth2 flow that does not include a client_secret.

Does the distinction between public and confidential clients flow make sense regarding the Client Credentials? Or is it fine to have possibly unsecure secrets store while handling a M2M authentication flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the authorization code flow and follow advice from [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252), to receive the login response on a loopback or private URI scheme based URI. You can run my [code example](https://authguidance.com/desktop-apps-overview/) to see how this works.

Client credentials flow is only usable by backend components when they act as OAuth clients. In a desktop app it would result in no real security, where anyone who can run the app can access data without authentication. The credentials are then also easily stolen by a malicious user.